# Pandas: Creating aggregated column in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

With the DataFrame below as an example,

```
In [83]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,2],'B':[1,2,1,2],'values':np.arange(10,30,5)})
df
Out[83]:
   A  B  values
0  1  1      10
1  1  2      15
2  2  1      20
3  2  2      25
```

What would be a simple way to generate a new column containing some aggregation of the data over one of the columns?

For example, if I sum `values` over items in `A`

```
In [84]:
df.groupby('A').sum()['values']
Out[84]:
A
1    25
2    45
Name: values
```

How can I get

```
   A  B  values  sum_values_A
0  1  1      10            25
1  1  2      15            25
2  2  1      20            45
3  2  2      25            45
```

Comment: Related: (1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346986/pandas-group-by-count-and-add-count-to-original-dataframe (2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432944/python-pandas-error-when-doing-groupby-counts

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
In [20]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,2],'B':[1,2,1,2],'values':np.arange(10,30,5)})

In [21]: df
Out[21]:
   A  B  values
0  1  1      10
1  1  2      15
2  2  1      20
3  2  2      25

In [22]: df['sum_values_A'] = df.groupby('A')['values'].transform(np.sum)

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
   A  B  values  sum_values_A
0  1  1      10            25
1  1  2      15            25
2  2  1      20            45
3  2  2      25            45
```

Answer (score 8):

I found a way using `join`:

```
In [101]:
aggregated = df.groupby('A').sum()['values']
aggregated.name = 'sum_values_A'
df.join(aggregated,on='A')

Out[101]:
   A  B  values  sum_values_A
0  1  1      10            25
1  1  2      15            25
2  2  1      20            45
3  2  2      25            45
```

Anyone has a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

This is not so direct but I found it very intuitive (the use of map to create new columns from another column) and can be applied to many other cases:

```
gb = df.groupby('A').sum()['values']

def getvalue(x):
    return gb[x]

df['sum'] = df['A'].map(getvalue)
df
```

Comment: Thanks, the map method seems pretty powerful. Will certainly use it often.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [15]: def sum_col(df, col, new_col):
   ....:     df[new_col] = df[col].sum()
   ....:     return df

In [16]: df.groupby("A").apply(sum_col, 'values', 'sum_values_A')
Out[16]: 
   A  B  values  sum_values_A
0  1  1      10            25
1  1  2      15            25
2  2  1      20            45
3  2  2      25            45
```