# Getting the result of groupby multiple columns and count directly in my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe (toy example below from another post) which you can generate with the code below ; I'd like to group by columns 'col1' and 'col2' and to count the number of occurences within each group like in this example: [How to count number of rows per group (and other statistics) in pandas group by?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/how-to-count-number-of-rows-per-group-and-other-statistics-in-pandas-group-by)

But to include the result directly into my dataframe like in this example (where there is only one column on which to group): [Pandas, group by count and add count to original dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346986/pandas-group-by-count-and-add-count-to-original-dataframe)

I have tried:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['col1','col2']).transform('count')
```

And:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])[['col1','col2']].transform('count')
```

But I get the same error both times:

```
ValueError: Length of passed values is 10, index implies 0
```

Any idea how I could get around with this without having to merge the result to my initial dataframe? In R dplyr this would be quite easy with `groupby`, `mutate` and `n()`....

Toy example:

```
  col1 col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
0    A    B  0.20 -0.61 -0.49  1.49
1    A    B -1.53 -1.01 -0.39  1.82
2    A    B -0.44  0.27  0.72  0.11
3    A    B  0.28 -1.32  0.38  0.18
4    C    D  0.12  0.59  0.81  0.66
5    C    D -0.13 -1.65 -1.64  0.50
6    C    D -1.42 -0.11 -0.18 -0.44
7    E    F -0.00  1.42 -0.26  1.17
8    E    F  0.91 -0.47  1.35 -0.34
9    G    H  1.48 -0.63 -1.14  0.17
```

Code to generate toy dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

keys = np.array([
   ['A', 'B'],
   ['A', 'B'],
     ['A', 'B'],
  ['A', 'B'],
     ['C', 'D'],
   ['C', 'D'],
   ['C', 'D'],
   ['E', 'F'],
   ['E', 'F'],
   ['G', 'H'] 
   ])

df = pd.DataFrame(
np.hstack([keys,np.random.randn(10,4).round(2)]), 
columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']
)

df[['col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']] = df[['col3', 'col4', 
'col5','col6']].astype(float)
```

Comment: What's the desired output ? Your question is unclear to me since by aggregating, you're having a diminished DataFrame, and therefore can't merge it with the previous one. Depending on the desired output, that might be feasible though.

Comment: The issue with your first method is that `transform('count')` returns a `DataFrame` which you are trying to assign to a single column, so that wont happen. In the second case that remains unchanged, you just have a 2 column `DataFrame` instead of 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

After @Alollz comment, the code can be reduced to a single line, without the concatenation:
`df['count'] = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col1'].transform('size')`

---

*Answer before the edit*

The workaround would be to make a `concatenated` column before applying the groupby.

After that you can use the `size` function inside your `transform` method.

Maybe not the most elegant, but it works.

**Code**

```
# make a concatenated column 
df['concat'] = df.col1 + df.col2

# perform the transformation asked
df['count'] = df.groupby(['concat'])['concat'].transform('size')

# drop the concat column
df.drop('concat', axis=1, inplace=True)


    col1col2col3    col4    col5    col6    count
0   A   B   -0.62   0.09    0.92    1.45    4
1   A   B   1.49    0.31    -0.40   -0.99   4
2   A   B   -1.30   1.01    -0.31   -0.32   4
3   A   B   -0.05   0.32    -1.45   -0.54   4
4   C   D   -1.30   1.26    1.80    0.50    3
5   C   D   0.75    0.13    0.49    -2.37   3
6   C   D   1.05    -0.96   -0.44   -1.00   3
7   E   F   0.31    -0.93   -1.78   -1.49   2
8   E   F   -0.23   0.30    0.77    1.46    2
9   G   H   -0.67   0.88    -0.26   -1.09   1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The `size` of everything within a group is the same since it includes `NaN` and DataFrames must be rectangular. (If you do `df.groupby(['col1','col2']).agg('size')`, you'll notice it only returns a single Series, unlike the DataFrame it returns for things like `.agg('count')`. So just pick any column you want to transform `df.groupby(['col1','col2']).col1.transform('size')`

Answer (score 1):

If you stack() the result of your groupby(), you will have a result that fits the length of your DataFrame's rows. Then, reset_index() will make it fit the previous DataFrame.

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).count().stack().reset_index()[0]
```

Will give you...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

keys = np.array([
   ['A', 'B'],
   ['A', 'B'],
     ['A', 'B'],
  ['A', 'B'],
     ['C', 'D'],
   ['C', 'D'],
   ['C', 'D'],
   ['E', 'F'],
   ['E', 'F'],
   ['G', 'H'] 
   ])

df = pd.DataFrame(
np.hstack([keys,np.random.randn(10,4).round(2)]), 
columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']
)

df[['col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']] = df[['col3', 'col4', 
'col5','col6']].astype(float)

df_count = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).count()
print(df_count)
#            col3  col4  col5  col6
# col1 col2                        
# A    B        4     4     4     4
# C    D        3     3     3     3
# E    F        2     2     2     2
# G    H        1     1     1     1
stacked_count = df_count.stack()
print(stacked_count)
# col1  col2      
# A     B     col3    4
#             col4    4
#             col5    4
#             col6    4
# C     D     col3    3
#             col4    3
#             col5    3
#             col6    3
# E     F     col3    2
#             col4    2
#             col5    2
#             col6    2
# G     H     col3    1
#             col4    1
#             col5    1
#             col6    1
# dtype: int64

ndf = stacked_count.reset_index()[0]
print(ndf)
# 0     4
# 1     4
# 2     4
# 3     4
# 4     3
# 5     3
# 6     3
# 7     3
# 8     2
# 9     2
# 10    2
# 11    2
# 12    1
# 13    1
# 14    1
# 15    1
# Name: 0, dtype: int64

df['count'] = ndf
print(df)
#   col1 col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  count
# 0    A    B -0.81 -1.39  0.07  0.71      4
# 1    A    B -1.37  1.72 -2.04  0.83      4
# 2    A    B -1.81 -0.53 -1.27 -0.83      4
# 3    A    B -1.05 -0.06 -1.78  0.81      4
# 4    C    D -1.40  0.36  0.94  1.90      3
# 5    C    D  0.65  0.49 -1.78  0.10      3
# 6    C    D -0.57 -0.08  1.11 -0.73      3
# 7    E    F  0.37  0.99 -1.62 -1.26      3
# 8    E    F  0.09 -0.03  1.27  0.80      2
# 9    G    H  0.26  0.71  0.05  0.48      2
```