# Count the number of occurrences of an event in times series

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series

I have this kind of dataframe :

```
shopping_center_id  device_local_date              day_of_week
19365   2                   01/09/2019 00:19                       7
27055   4                   01/09/2019 00:26                       7
27014   4                   01/09/2019 00:26                       7
26906   4                   01/09/2019 00:26                       7
28422   4                   01/09/2019 00:26                       7
```

I would like to count the number of times a shopping center id has been visited at a given time ?
I tried many combinations with groupby and count and didn't get any the wanted result
Thanks in advance

```
data_new['Count']=data_new.groupby('device_local_date')['shopping_center_id'].count()
```

this gave me a column of Count filled with "Nan"

Comment: what is expected result?

Comment: maybe first display result without assigning to new column.

Comment: you don't need \ in code when you put in question.

Comment: code gives me two values and it simply doesn't how to convert it to 6 rows which you have in original dataframe.

Comment: you have to use `.transform('count')` instread of `.count()` like in answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346986/pandas-group-by-count-and-add-count-to-original-dataframe