# How to append a new column on to an existing dataframe that contains a conditional count which is also grouped by

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a new column to my existing dataframe that contains a conditional count, grouped by another column in the dataframe.

In my example I am counting when "Severity" ==2 and grouping by "Data Tech Group". I am achieving this count by doing the below:

```
df.loc[df.Severity == 2].groupby("AssignedGroup").count()
```

Here is my current dataframe:

```
Data Tech Group       Sev 1-4 count
LHR53 Data Tech             19
LHR56 Data Tech             10
LHR57 Data Tech             18
LHR54 Data Tech             76
LHR64 Data Tech              5
LHR55 Data Tech            137
LHR59 Data Tech            149
```

Below is the data frame I want to achieve, where if "Data Tech Group" does not meet the condition (if there are no Sev2 tickets or value is NaN), it is marked in the row as 0.

```
 Data Tech Group       Sev 1-4 count   Sev 2 count
    LHR53 Data Tech             19          1
    LHR56 Data Tech             10          0
    LHR57 Data Tech             18          3
    LHR54 Data Tech             76          0
    LHR64 Data Tech              5          0
    LHR55 Data Tech            137          1
    LHR59 Data Tech            149          2
```

Also, I am not sure if I need to mention this, but the index I have specified manually and is based on "Data Tech Group".

Comment: You may have missed some information in the question?

Comment: Apologies what have I missed? @spramuditha

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of [Pandas: Creating aggregated column in DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13257199/8510370)

Comment: Sev2 data? Or is that also taken from the same Severity column? If so, in simple terms what you need is to groupby a column that is already groupby?

Comment: @spramuditha all of the data for Sev1-4, Sev2, Sev3, etc is all in one column "Severity". Could you provide me an example on how to do this?

Comment: Check the answer, it'll get there if I have understood your question correctly. I'll amend if there's a more elegant answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with a direct answer, but having understood what you need follow this method. It'll get the answer. If I get a shorter fancier one, I'll amend the answer.

1. Make a duplicate of the df. Evaluate `df.loc[df.Severity == 2].groupby("AssignedGroup").count()` similar to what you did with **Sev 1-4 count**
2. Use `idx_common = df1.index.intersection(df2.index.intersection)` to get the common indexes to both cases.
3. Use either df1 or df2 to filter the necessary indexes with `df = df1[idx_common]`

Comment: Is there any reason why I can't just do:       
 df["Sev 2 count"] = df.loc[df.Severity == 2].groupby("AssignedGroup").count()

Comment: Probably because pd.Series length in left will not be length of df.